# how can I access the servlet when on the server?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web

I have a lot of errors when I upload my files.  However, they work perfectly on my localhost.

I have a form which its action is a servlet.  I know that the structure of files force me to put all .class files in the directory `/WEB-INF/classes`.  The problem is when I write this as form action `/WEB-INF/classes/myservlet` I get this message:

> ```
> "You don't have permission to access /WEB-INF/classes/myservleton this server".
> ```

What do I need to do to correct this problem?

UPDATE : this is part of `web.xml`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>addservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>app.addservlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>addservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/addservlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is the requested URL when I submit form :

`http://mydomain.com/addservlet`

And I get Not Found error

`The requested URL /addservlet was not found on this server`

Comment: That folder is only accessible from the server. Did you try `action="/myservlet"`? After mapping the servlet of course.

Comment: I did not map the servlet yet I will try what Tor P said below =)

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to map the servlet in your web.xml file...  see the first example in http://static.springsource.com/projects/tc-server/6.0/getstart/rgswebxml.html

i.e

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>my.package.myservlet</servlet-class> (or what ever package you use)
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/myservlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Then you point the action to /myservlet

Comment: Many thanks for answering me . I did this But nothing was changed . I will update my question to let you see

Comment: Your package name is "app"?  Then you need to put the .class file in /WEB-INF/classes/app and after that you put web.xml in the WEB-INF/ folder

Comment: What do you use for development? You should look into making a WAR file (=Web ARchive, any decent IDE like Eclipse or netbeans can do this) of the entire application and rather deploy this one to the "war deployment folder" on your server

Comment: I use netbeans .. I think it should do that .. about the location of of. Class , I put all of them in this directory .. so what my problem seem to be?

Comment: Which server are you running? Did you put web.xml in the correct location?

Comment: Tomcat , is this what you mean?  Yes I put it in the correct location in WEB-INF

Comment: strange... whenever I update the web.xml file in jetty (8.1) the application automatically redeploys... is there anything in the tomcat logs?

Answer (score 0):

A servlet runs a java class when the right url is send to the server. This is done by the "mapping" property you have to define in web.xml. Resources under WEB-INF are always protected from being accessed through the url.

Comment: Not that accessing a class file would make sense anyway.